# Difference between $\mathbb{F}^I$ and $\mathbb{F}^{(I)}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $I$ is a set of indices (say infinite), and $\mathbb{F}$ is a field.

I'm asked to prove that $\mathbb{F}^{(I)}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^I$.

I understand that $\mathbb{F}^I := \{f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{F}\}$. However, I don't understand the difference between $\mathbb{F}^{(I)}$ and $\mathbb{F}^I$. How are they different?

(I'm not looking for the proof; I would just like to disambiguate these so I can better approach the problem.)

Comment: $\mathbb F^{(I)} = \{f \in \mathbb F^I : \textrm{the set } f^{-1}(\mathbb F \setminus \{0\}) = \{i \in I : f(i) \neq 0\} \textrm{ is finite}\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @azif00. I'm still a bit confused as to what this means. Is it possible for an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb F^I$ is the set of **all** functions from $I$ to $\Bbb F$.

$\Bbb F^{(I)}$ is the set of those functions from $I$ to $F$ that assume the value $0$ almost all of the time (so only finitely many exceptions at most). So if $I=\Bbb N$ for concreteness, then $f(n)=1$ for all $n$ or $f(n)=n$ for all $n$ is in the first set but not in the second as they assume $0$ only at most once. A function like $f(n)=0$ for all $n >2$ and $n+1$ otherwise, *is* in the second set, though as it only has three non-zero values, $f(0)=1,f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=3$. Trivial examples, but it's to show the point.

Comment: Well explained; thank you.